# Opening image via default viewer in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core

Built out a Console app to try to open an image in Windows using .NET Core. Kept getting an error.

```
Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(tempFile));
```

Results in:

> Win32Exception: The specified executable is not a valid application
>   for this OS platform.

What do I need to do to make it open in Windows' default viewer, in my case, the Windows Photo Viewer? For now, I've resorted to display the full image path to copy-paste.

It works if I use .NET 4.6.2, but not .NetCoreApp 1.1. I know its something to do with making it cross-platform friendly(?) but what...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference that prevents this from working is that `ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute` defaults to `false` on .NET Core, and cannot be controlled on Windows. Due to that, the program is trying to launch the image file as an executable, which is not possible. Instead, you can essentially use `Process.Start` to emulate a shell command in order to open the file with the system's default viewer.

```
Process.Start("cmd", $"/c {pathToFile}");
```

Similarly, `xdg-open` can be used on Linux (generally speaking), and `open` can be used on OSX.

Comment: That works! I see the "/c" switch is basically "carries out the command specified by the string and then terminates".